# Azure AD B2C login_hint not working with PasswordReset User Journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In our custom signIn/SignUp policy, whenever a user clicks on "Forgot your Password?" link, we don't want the user to re-type the email address when it navigates to passwordReset policy, so wanted to make use of login_hint, which is not working.

Here is my code

```xml
<UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>

<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
    <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

When we run the policy , we notice "{OIDC:LoginHint}" displayed in the EmailAddress text box.

Please let me know how I can make login_hint to work with PasswordReset UserJourney.

Thanks,

Comment: Any thoughts please

Comment: How are you passing the login hint to this policy?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett, we are appending  

&login_hint=xxxxxxxxx@mailinator.com, when we build the url for PasswordRest Policy

Comment: This is by design and B2C doesn't support login_hint for password reset policy.

Comment: @Ramakrishna, Is there is any other way to handle this. we don't want user to re-type the email address in PasswordReset

Comment: For now, it is not possible :-( but yes by using custom JS. But this feature not yet available. B2C already have this feature in the roadmap and you can vote for the same @ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br

Comment: This has been enabled. Doc is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

Comment: @Ramakrishna I know this is quite old but, I believe that LoginHint works only if the first step of the UJ is a CombinedSignInAndSignUp. Is that correct?